# apply multiple pos argument in lemmatization

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string. I want to apply lemmatization on it.

```
str = "i want better dogs"

str = str.split(" ") 
for w in str: wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)
```

I'm getting output:

> i want better dog

When i am running this loop:

```
for w in str: 
    wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w,pos='a')
```

I'm getting this output:

> i want good dogs
>
> Blockquote

What i want is the combination of both the loops. i.e ** `i want good dog`**
how can i do it? Is there a way to add multiple pos like `v(verb),n(noun)` ?

Answer (score 7):

What you want, is to first run a POS tagger on your text to find out the parts-of-speech, and then lemmatize accordingly.

POS tag using `nltk.tag`:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("i want better dogs"))
[('i', 'NN'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('better', 'JJR'), ('dogs', 'NNS')]
```

Then you can check whether a tag starts with `NN`, `JJ`, or `VB`, and ignore all other tags:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

def lemmatize_all(sentence):
    wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
        if tag.startswith("NN"):
            yield wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='n')
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            yield wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='v')
        elif tag.startswith('JJ'):
            yield wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='a')
        else:
            yield word

print(' '.join(lemmatize_all("i want better dogs")))
# prints 'i want good dog'
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you need to specify 'a' or 'n' is that the process needs to know the part of speech in order to decide the lemma.

For example "building" can be both a the present participle of a verb "build", and a noun. So `lemmatize("building",'n') == "building"` whereas `lemmatize("building",'v') == "build"`. If you applied all the rules it would incorrectly change "i want a better building" to  "i want a good build", which would be incorrect. Identifying the part of speech cannot be done algorithmically, so it must be specified by the user.

If there are specific word, such as "better", you can check for yourself, before passing to wordnet.

Comment: This helped me understand the problem.